# Filter data.frame using sqldf and/or dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

I need to find null values inside a data.frame using sqldf or dplyr libraries.

I know that I can use na.omit() to do that, but I cant find the way to do the same using sqldf or dplyr libraries.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: For sqldf: `SELECT * FROM df WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Please provide some test data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`drop_na` from tidyr will drop all rows that contain missing values in any column (or in columns that you specify).

Here's the example from the [documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/drop_na.html):

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"))
df %>% drop_na()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x y    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 a    
df %>% drop_na(x)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x y    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 NA
```